# Joomla website (and its db ) + Python(add,edit, upgrade in another db ) application Integration

Tags: python, joomla, integration

How can one integrate a web application(built in joomla) to (communicate, update db, do cron jobs)  to a application in python(or django) , Since my website has huge no of visitors, I feel should there be a seperate application to be an interpreter between these two(joomla,python) like some sort of Initialization engine to communicate and exchange its database between these two sites(Option1) or Is it possible to have API's in joomla app to communicate and update regularly to Python app(Option2). please let me know I am hoping a solution that can help me....

## Heading

Answer (score 0):

[Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) supports both PHP and Python:

> Thrift is a software framework for
>   scalable cross-language services
>   development. It combines a software
>   stack with a code generation engine to
>   build services that work efficiently
>   and seamlessly between C++, Java,
>   Python, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl,
>   Haskell, C#, Cocoa, JavaScript,
>   Node.js, Smalltalk, and OCaml.